# Which questions best showcase the site?

Tags: discussion

I recall seeing a picture of various stack site promotional goodies and there were star wars ones that featured a question and a link to the site.  This got me thinking of various ways we could promote RPG.SE.  **Which questions on the site best showcase the site?**  A good rule of thumb is how well the question and the answers fall in line with the intended rules of the site.

I'd like to make a few flyers out of the best responses to post in a few places where gamers might see them.

Comment: When you make a flyer, please also post it here! (There might be a few people who would also post them in a few places where other gamers might see them.)